# Headphones microphone not working

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone, headphones

Whenever I plug my headphones (I have tried many headphones) into my laptop's combined input/output audio jack, sound is working but the microphone is not recognized in pavucontrol. I can only see the laptop's internal microphone.

I have read many different questions on the forums and in most of them, answers suggest to edit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf. I have tried adding the following line:

```
options snd_hda_intel model=<model>
```

with different options for <model> found here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/late...io/models.html. Because I have an asus laptop with an alc255 card I tried models which had "asus" or "alc255" in the name. With some models, after a reboot, when I connected my headphones, a prompt appeared that asked me to select between headphones, headset and microphone, so that was an improvement. However the microphone still didn't work.

What am I doing wrong? I need to have my headphones mic fixed because built-in microphone is noisy. I don't want to go back to Windows because of this.